# Looking for a taxonomy of web attacks

Tags: web-application, firewalls, http

I am working on semantic representation of firewall rules but could not find a good taxonomy of Web attacks in terms of HTTP protocol. I do find web attack classification i.e XSS attack, SQL attack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, so I don't know exactly what you are looking for. However, in this paper a taxonomy based on HTTP methods is described: 
`http://140.127.40.47/psnl/publications/2008ICHIT_taxonomy.pdf`

Answer (score 2):

The attacks I know about are:

- SQL injection
- Cross site scripting (XSS)
- Cross site request forgery
- Session hijacking
- Bruteforce attacks
- Executable code in uploads
- Command line injection
- Session fixation

I think if anyone has something close to a taxonomy for web based attacks it will be OWASP.

Answer (score 0):

The MISP project has assembled a large number of descriptors to annotate IOCs in the form of a taxonomy, where each tag is a `(namespace, predicate, value)` triple.

Those are defined in JSON format here:

- https://github.com/MISP/misp-taxonomies, https://www.circl.lu/doc/misp-taxonomies/
- https://github.com/MISP/misp-galaxy, https://www.misp.software/galaxy.html

Both of those are designed to be used by non-MISP tools.

From those lists, these may be esp. interesting.  (Found by searching for sets including `XSS` on the taxonomy listing page).

- https://www.circl.lu/doc/misp-taxonomies/#_circl
- https://www.circl.lu/doc/misp-taxonomies/#_enisa
- https://www.circl.lu/doc/misp-taxonomies/#_europol_event
- https://www.circl.lu/doc/misp-taxonomies/#_veris

The "Mapping of Taxonomies" at the bottom of that page provides a nice summary of similar concepts referenced in multiple taxonomies (e.g. all categories with a concept for `ddos`): 
https://www.circl.lu/doc/misp-taxonomies/#_mapping_of_taxonomies